# adding facebook login to spree 1.0.x

Tags: devise, omniauth, spree

I am using spree 1.0.3 and rails 3.1.4. I remember a year ago searching for this and it seemed to be fairly easy with devise and omniauth. However, I can't seem to find any of the concrete tutorials i found before on how to do this. Also, there have been major revisions (spree 1.0, omniauth 1.0) so I'm not sure how valid any of the older tutorials would be (there don't seem to be any new ones).  I see the spree_social plugin in github, but that seems to be in early beta still.

I see that the [rails dog demo site](http://demo.spreecommerce.com/login) has facebook login, but I don't know what they used to create that.

**Is deviseable omniauth still viable for spree 1.0? If so, are there any demos or source code out there? If not, are there any options out there that provide as smooth an integration to social media logins as devise/omniauth did with spree?**

Answer (score 1):

Zyren,

I believe that https://github.com/spree/spree_social is being used for the demo. It should do most of what you need to do.